# How can i get value from timefield combo in a grid EXTJS6?

Tags: extjs, grid

a have a grid in EXTJS6 thats cointains the working hours for a week. All these hours are of timefield type and separated by Morning in, Morning out, Afternoon in, Afternoon out.

All hours should be added and compared to a total working hours (if is true show in a label YES, otherwise, says NO). This comprobation works fine when i add a new default values row (8:30, 13:00, 15:00, 19:00), but exist moments that i need to edit each cell one by one and after check the sum again.

The sum algoritm works this way: When i click the button o add day, creates a new row with default values and add to grid count +1, then sum all hours values in array whith a for cicle and check with the total hours values.

The problem ocurrs when i click in a cell (timefieldtype) and i edit the value. This value is changed and is added at the total when i click in the add day button, but not in the moment that is changed. For this reason i want to get the cell timefield value to make other estrategy to operate this value, in other words, operate the old value in timefield with the new value.

How can i to get the old timefield value in a cell?.

Image of a grid:

[image]

This is the view controller method that listen when made click in the timefield combo of a grid.

```
     onTimefieldSelect: function(combo, record, eOpts) {
        var value = new Date(combo.getValue());

        hora = value.getHours();
        minuto = (value.getMinutes() === 0)?'00':value.getMinutes();
        hora_combo = hora +':'+minuto;
        combo.setValue(hora_combo);
        console.log('hora '+hora+' '+minuto+" (desde onTimefieldSelect)");
        var valor_actual = grid.editingPlugin.getActiveRecord();
        console.log(valor_actual);
}
```

then is rendered in this method (one for each column)

```
    renderHora1: function(value, metaData, record, rowIndex, colIndex, store, view) {
    //return(this.renderHora(value));
    if(!isNaN(new Date(value)))
    {
        return(this.renderHora(value));
    }else{
        return value;
    }
},
```

and the method to add day:

```
 onAgregarDiaClick: function(button, e, eOpts) {

    dias_store  = button.up('grid').getStore().count();
    console.log(dias_store+" dia (desde agregardiaclick)");

    horas_semanales = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('numberfield[name=num_horasSemanales]')[0].getValue();
    hora_inicial = 0;
    dif_hora_total = 8.80;
    dif_hora_med_jor = 4.48;
    hora_entera = 0; // VARIABLE QUE DETERMINA EL VALOR DE LA SUMA DE HORAS SIN DECIMALES.
    cuenta_grid    = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('[itemId=grid_jornadaLaboral]')[0].getStore().getCount();





    if (horas_semanales === 0) {

         Ext.Msg.show
        ({
            title:'Advertencia',
            msg: 'No has ingresado las horas semanales' ,
            icon: Ext.MessageBox.WARNING,
            buttons: Ext.MessageBox.OK
        });
    } else {

        if(dias_store < 7)
    {


        grideditable = button.up('grid');
        opcion = new form_48.model.JornadaLaboral.mdl_JornadaDiaria({
            'dia_codigo'    : 8,
            'dia_nombre'    : 'Seleccione...',
            'entrada_manana': '08:30',
            'salida_manana' : '13:18',
            'entrada_tarde' : '15:00',
            'salida_tarde'  : '19:00'
        });
        if(dias_store == 6)
        button.disable();

        var editor = button.up('grid').editingPlugin;
        //editor.cancelEdit();

        console.log(cuenta_grid);
         console.log("**********************************************")

        if(cuenta_grid === 0){

            button.up('grid').getStore().insert(dias_store+1, opcion);
            button.up('grid').getStore().sort('dia_codigo', 'ASC');
            //cuenta_grid = cuenta_grid + 1;

        }
        //editor.startEditByPosition({row: dias_store+1, column: 0});



    }




        if( hora_inicial < horas_semanales ){
        hora_inicial = dif_hora_total;
        activa_suma = true;

        if (activa_suma ==true) {


            for (var i = 0; i < cuenta_grid; i++)
            {

                var ent_mnna = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('[itemId=grid_jornadaLaboral]')[0].getStore().data.items[i].data.entrada_manana;
                var sal_mnna = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('[itemId=grid_jornadaLaboral]')[0].getStore().data.items[i].data.salida_manana;
                var ent_tard = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('[itemId=grid_jornadaLaboral]')[0].getStore().data.items[i].data.entrada_tarde;
                var sal_tard = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('[itemId=grid_jornadaLaboral]')[0].getStore().data.items[i].data.salida_tarde;


                var ent_mnna_sum = form_48.app.getController('FormateoNumero').fecha_hora(ent_mnna);
                var sal_mnna_sum = form_48.app.getController('FormateoNumero').fecha_hora(sal_mnna);
                var ent_tard_sum = form_48.app.getController('FormateoNumero').fecha_hora(ent_tard);
                var sal_tard_sum = form_48.app.getController('FormateoNumero').fecha_hora(sal_tard);

                //OBTENEMOS LAS DIFERENCIAS DE HORAS DE LA MANANA Y DE LA TARDE (EJ. 8:30 -13:18 = 04:48)
                dif_hora_manana = form_48.app.getController('FormateoNumero').resta_horas(ent_mnna_sum,sal_mnna_sum);
                dif_hora_tarde  = form_48.app.getController('FormateoNumero').resta_horas(ent_tard_sum,sal_tard_sum);


                //SUMAMOS LAS DIFERENCIAS DE HORAS DE LA MANANA Y DE LA TARDE PARA OBTENER EL TOTAL DE HORAS TRABAJADO AL DIA.
                suma_horas_jornada = form_48.app.getController('FormateoNumero').suma_horas(dif_hora_manana,dif_hora_tarde);
                dif_hora_total = (dif_hora_total + suma_horas_jornada);


                console.log(suma_horas_jornada+ " horas jornada(desdea gregardiaclick)");
                console.log(hora_entera+ " diferencia horas sin decimal (desde agregardiaclick)");

                console.log("-------------------------------------------------------------------");

                console.log(ent_mnna);


                // Ext.ComponentQuery.query('numberfield[name=num_horas_grid]')[0].setValue(num_horas_grid);
                //console.log(dif_hora_total);



            }
            hora_entera = Math.trunc(dif_hora_total);

            if(hora_entera <= horas_semanales){

                //alert("dif_hora2: "+dif_hora_total);
                button.up('grid').getStore().insert(dias_store+1, opcion);
                button.up('grid').getStore().sort('dia_codigo', 'ASC');

            }else{

                Ext.Msg.show
                ({
                    title:'Advertencia',
                    msg: 'No se puede ingresar la jornada ya que se exceden por ' +(dif_hora_total- horas_semanales).toFixed(1) + ' horas el maximo establecido en el campo:<center><b>"Horas Semanales"</b></center>' ,
                    icon: Ext.MessageBox.WARNING,
                    buttons: Ext.MessageBox.OK

                });
                activa_suma == false;
            }
                console.log(dif_hora_total+ " suma actual de horas(desde agregardiaclick)");

               if((hora_entera || dif_hora_total)=== horas_semanales){

                Ext.ComponentQuery.query('displayfield[name=dsp_cumple_horas]')[0].setValue('SI');

               console.log(horas_semanales+ " horas semanales(desde agregardiaclick)");
            }else{

                Ext.ComponentQuery.query('displayfield[name=dsp_cumple_horas]')[0].setValue('NO');

            }


        }//fin if cuentagrid
    }




     //horas_semanales = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('numberfield[name=num_horasSemanales]')[0].getValue();


    }


},
```

Sorry for my English. I hope you can help me with an ideas.
Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

To get this to work you will need to use `1/1/2008` as your base date, because ExtJS this as it's default date for Time Calculations, so start your dates like this:

`var date = Ext.Date.clearTime(new Date('1/1/2008'));`

Then you can add editors to your grid, with:

```
editor: {
    xtype: 'timefield',
    format: 'H:i' // 24 hour format
}
```

I setup this example using the ViewModel, formulas and default dates you can use as guide:

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/222c